# Swift: could not find an overload for ' ' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: animation, uiview, double, swift

So what I need is an image to rotate continuously. The problem is at 
///
    UIView.animateWithDuration() (0.01, animations: { ///

where it says: Could not find an overload for 'animateWithDuration' that accepts the supplied arguments

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let schedule = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("rotate"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    schedule.fire()

    func rotate() {
        angle = angle + 1

        UIView.animateWithDuration() (0.01, animations: { 
            self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ((self.angle) / 180.0 * M_PI));
            })
    }
}

@IBOutlet var imageView : UIImageView

var angle = 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove extra `()` after `animateWithDuration`

Comment: ![Here's one screenshot.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kfd0j778pnxfwx/Screenshot%202014-06-12%2000.37.37.png).

Comment: @BryanChen Already tried that. It's the same error.

Comment: The [new UIView docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/) seem to suggest that that method has been depreciated.

Comment: @68cherries Which method? `animateWithDuration`? I don't see any indication of this, am I missing something?

Comment: @0x7fffffff, now I get the Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT. I guess I'm doing something wrong at the highest level.

Comment: @perteraul That's a different issue. You should start a new question with all the details.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I searched a little, it's a deployment issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bryan Chen pointed out, you have an extra () in the method call. But, that's not your only problem. Your `angle` variable is an Int, when it's expected to be a Double which causes this error. Change your variable declaration to be a Double

```
var angle = 0.0
```

And use doubles throughout, like when modifying the variable.

```
angle = angle + 1.0
```

And then this will work without error.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.01, animations: {
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ((self.angle) / 180.0 * M_PI));
})
```